# Electron - SetTimeout for ipcRenderer.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, settimeout

Hi I'm calling the `ipcRenderer.send()` from the `index.html` file.

What i'm trying to do is to delay the function call by 5 seconds. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm trying to do essentially:

`setTimeout(ipcRenderer.send('startYellowApple', ["bob", "cat"]), 5000);`

and here's how I execute this in a regular Native Javascript function:

```
function start(){
  setTimeout(ipcRenderer.send('startYellowApple', ["bob", "cat"]), 5000);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

However I manage to make some progress by using this method.. However it freezes up my entire electron program until the 5 seconds is over which is really not ideal:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
   let currentDate = null;
   do {
     currentDate = Date.now();
   } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function start(){
  sleep(5000);
  ipcRenderer.send('startYellowApple', ["bob", "cat"]);
}
```

Could someone help me out please? Thanks!

Comment: You are calling the funcion without no delay. The syntax should be `setTimeout(() => ipcRenderer.send(...), 5000)`

Comment: You don't understand async/await in JS. Go and learn JS first

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you pass your callback to setTimeout function.

```
ipcRenderer.send('startYellowApple', ["bob", "cat"])
```

is actually a function call, it will invoke immediately, you should wrap the call inside a function to achieve what you want.

```
function start(){
   setTimeout(() => ipcRenderer.send('startYellowApple', ["bob", "cat"]), 5000);
}
```